# Children are not mapping properly in elastic to parents

Tags: elasticsearch

```
"chods": {
  "mappings": {
     "chod": {
        "properties": {
           "state": {
              "type": "text"
           }
        }
     },
     "chods": {},
     "variant": {
        "_parent": {
           "type": "chod"
        },
        "_routing": {
           "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
           "percentage": {
              "type": "double"
           }
        }
     }
  }
},
```

When I execute:

```
PUT /chods/variant/565?parent=36442
{ // some data }
```

It returns:

```
{
  "_index":"chods",
  "_type":"variant",
  "_id":"565",
  "_version":6,
  "result":"updated",
  "_shards":{
     "total":2,
     "successful":1,
     "failed":0
  },
  "created":false
}
```

But when I run this query:

```
GET /chods/variant/565?parent=36442
```

It returns variant with parent=36443

```
{
   "_index": "chods",
   "_type": "variant",
   "_id": "565",
   "_version": 7,
   "_routing": "36443",
   "_parent": "36443",
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      ...
   }
}
```

Why it returns with parent 36443 and not 36442?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to reproduce this with your steps, I got the expected result (version=36442). I noticed that after your PUT of the document with `"_parent": "36442"` the output is `"_version":6`. In your GET of the document, `"_version": 7` is returned. Is it possible that you posted another version of the document?

I also noticed that `GET /chods/variant/565?parent=36443` would not actually filter by the parent id - the query parameter is disregarded. If you actually want to filter by parent id, this is the query you're looking for:

```
GET /chods/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "parent_id": {
      "type": "variant",
      "id": "36442"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well I checked logs and no I am not. Or maybe I am because I am doing two PUT calls but with different parent number. Also if I do GET request with the version number then it returns version_conflict_engine_exception

Comment: Which parent number do you put last? I'm pretty sure you get a `version_conflict_engine_exception` if you try to update a version of a document that is not the latest.

Comment: The last parent is 36443 but I get exception during fetching data like GET /chods/variant/565?parent=36442&version=1 and not during updating

Comment: So the document will have the latest version of parent you PUT - that's why the parent=36443. You are getting the `version_conflict_engine_exception` because you are asking for version=1, which is not the latest version of the document. If you change that to version=7 or whatever the latest version is, your query will work. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#get-versioning) is documentation for the version parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As @fylie pointed out the main problem is that if you use same id of the document you will get your document overridden by last version - sort of

Lets say that we have index /tests and type "a" which is child of type "test" and we do following commands:

```
PUT /tests/a/50?parent=25
{
  "item": "C"
}

PUT /tests/a/50?parent=26
{
  "item": "D"
}

PUT /tests/a/50?parent=50
{
  "item": "E",
  "item2": "F",
}
```

What the result will be? Well it can result in creating 1 - 3 documents.
If it will route to the same shard, you will end up with one document, which will have 3 versions.

If it will route to 3 different shards, you will end up with 3 new documents.

Comment: [Here's](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-two-documents-with-the-same-id-exist-if-they-have-different-parents/10988/5) a post about why that is if you're curious. :) (I was curious)